# Make clickable UI-elements for windows Phone 8.1 apps maps

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Phone 8.1 App , C#

I would like to let the user add Pushpins ( which apparently are called MapIcons ) to the map and when the user clicks the newly created Pushpin some other ui-elements should appear.

But apparently MapIcons are not clickable and you can not inherit from them since they are sealed, so no luck in making them clickable.

I tried to just extend from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button , but those have not Location, probably because they do not belong to the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps-namespace. So I can not really add them to the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl.Children or Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl.MapElements, since they will not be on the map where I would want them to be.

So how do you make a clickable ui-element that I can give a location on the map?

Answer (score 2):

You can throw pretty much anything you want on there and just bind to the MapControl.Location attached property for the object placement as long as they're children of a map parent.

See more detail explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx#showing_xaml_controls_and_shapes_on_the_map) in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the connection between my question and the link you posted. There are some xaml definitions and then an ellipse ( which has no clickhandler ). How do i "just bind" the MapControl.Location to any given object i create?

Comment: So in that link they're showing how to put controls on a map. Which could be anything from a Button to a TextBox to whatever. You could style a Button for instance to look like whatever you want, including pushpin. Or even go as simple as something like a shape which when filled does have hittestvisibility and will accept events. Make more sense?

Comment: Well I already wrote that I tried to add a button and I sure can do that. But that button ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.aspx ) doesn't have a location attribute. Or do you mean something like this http://hastebin.com/sudowomuno.xaml ( don't have my ide here atm )? If you mean this i have two problems a) I want to create this button on runtime in C# and more than just one and b) I dont know what maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location} means or how I connect it to my datastructures.

Comment: So it sounds like you could just do a MapItemsControl and feed it a collection, your second link appears legit and what I'm talking about.

Comment: You read that my second link was just an example and that I have two problems with it? I don't know how I "feed a collection" to xaml at runtime and I don't know how to bind the MapControl.Location to my datastructures.